# Why does the statement "2i;" NOT cause a compiler error?

Tags: c, syntax

Instead of `2*i`, I carelessly wrote `2i`:

```
int foo(int i)
{
    2i;
    return 2i;
}
```

I expected the compiler to catch the error. But it did not. So is `2i` a valid statement in C? If so what does it do? Puzzled!

I compiled using gcc version 5.3.0 and here is the assembly output:

```
    .file   "strange.c"
    .text
    .globl  foo
    .type   foo, @function
foo:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    nop
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   foo, .-foo
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 5.3.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: What compiler is that?

Comment: I don't work with `_Complex` numbers. After some reading in the standard and the provided link, I think @iharob's answer is correct.

Comment: @Olaf The fastet Fourier Transform in the West *fftw* uses the `_Complex` type. I found this out while writing a data processing software for my thesis (*Physics actually, not computer science or alike*) - (*I had to apply a low pass filter, so convolution so Fast Fourier Transform, so fftw*).

Comment: @iharob: Hmm, is that faster than the ffte and if not, am I allowed to use the faster if I live in the west, but east of you? ;-) Seriously: thanks for the info. As it looks, the C standard does not even support a similar simple notation with C11.

Comment: A very good example of ".. not 'Eureka' but 'That's funny...'"!

Answer (score 106, accepted):

This is a [*gcc* extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Complex.html), and `2i` is the imaginary constant [image]. So you can write a complex number like so:

```
#include <complex.h>

_Complex x = 4 + 5i;
```

Comment: Looking at the assembly code, function `foo` does not return `0` as it should?

Comment: Wow, that came as a surprise! Will you tell me why it worked even when i did not include complex.h header file?

Comment: @daltonfury42 The header is for the `_Complex` type, `2i` is a constant (*as gcc understands it*). Add the `std=c99` or `std=c11` flag combined with `-Wall` and you shall see a warning. Also, indeed it does not return `0` but since the return type should be `_Complex` and the value `0 + 2i`, you can't inspect it with `printf()`. So perhaps that is just the **real** part `0`!

Comment: @daltonfury42: You don't have to `#include <float.h>` (or `math.h`) to get support for _floating point constants_ either.

Comment: @iharob Correct me if I am wrong: The constant `2i` is something understood by the compiler directly and so is float as @Olaf illustrates?

Comment: @daltonfury42 That's right. Header files don't change the language syntax, they just declare things like variables, functions, types, etc.

Comment: @daltonfury42 Although it could have been possible for recognition of this syntax to be controlled by a `#pragma`, which `complex.h` could issue. But they didn't do it this way.

Comment: here is a way to look at it: would 2f or 2u confuse you? They are literal suffixes to make a constant be a float or an unsigned int. There are user defined literals for time spans, imaginary numbers, and so on. If you're writing standard C++, you would have to include an appropriate header and use an appropriate namespace for `2i` to mean `2 times the square root of -1`. The only weird thing here is gcc doing that for you without the include and the using.

Comment: @Kate Gregory My gcc C compiler complains about `2f`.  Confident FP constants need a `.`

Comment: @chux you're right. `2u` or `2.f` are the builtins. Also `2L` etc

Comment: Is it possible to stack `i` with `u`, `f`, etc?

Comment: I was expecting it to be some obscure, signed analog to `2u`! XD

Comment: this is very interesting, how does system prints constant numbers ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I don't understand your question.

Comment: @iharob how to print  `_Complex` object - does gcc provides any format string - I was interested to know (i am asking without trying myself)

Answer (score 14):

`2i` is a `gcc` extension for a complex integer literal, a pure imaginary number twice the square root of `-1`.  This extension is supported by `clang` as well.

It is somewhat surprising that your compiling with `gcc 5.4.0` produces the posted assembly output:

- Compiling on http://gcc.godbolt.org/# I get a compilation error from `gcc` 5.3.0: `http://gcc.godbolt.org/#`: `error: cannot convert '__complex__ int' to 'int' in return`.
- The posted assembly code for function `foo` is incorrect: it does not return `0`.  Converting the complex integer constant `2i` to `int` should return its real part `0`.

Conversely, with `clang` 3.7, it compiles without a warning and generates optimum code, but of course not what you expect:

```
foo(int):                       # @foo(int)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    retq
```

This syntax can be combined with other suffixes in any order. Compiling the code below with `clang -Weverything` gives me appropriate warnings `warning: imaginary constants are a GNU extension [-Wgnu-imaginary-constant]`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    /* complex integer literals */
    printf("sizeof(2i) = %zd\n", sizeof(2i));
    printf("sizeof(2ui) = %zd\n", sizeof(2ui));
    printf("sizeof(2li) = %zd\n", sizeof(2li));
    printf("sizeof(2lli) = %zd\n", sizeof(2lli));
    /* complex floating point literals */
    printf("sizeof(2.i) = %zd\n", sizeof(2.i));
    printf("sizeof(2.fi) = %zd\n", sizeof(2.fi));
    printf("sizeof(2e0fi) = %zd\n", sizeof(2e0fi));
    printf("sizeof(2e0i) = %zd\n", sizeof(2e0i));
    /* alternate order */
    printf("sizeof(2il) = %zd\n", sizeof(2il));
    printf("sizeof(2ill) = %zd\n", sizeof(2ill));
    printf("sizeof(2.if) = %zd\n", sizeof(2.if));

    return 0;
}
```

It produces this output in my environment:

```
sizeof(2i) = 8
sizeof(2ui) = 8
sizeof(2li) = 16
sizeof(2lli) = 16
sizeof(2.i) = 16
sizeof(2.fi) = 8
sizeof(2e0fi) = 8
sizeof(2e0i) = 16
sizeof(2il) = 16
sizeof(2ill) = 16
sizeof(2.if) = 8
```

Try the last one with your syntax coloring editor `;-)`

Comment: Well, this is what I got when I used GCC 5.3.0 on my PC running Arch Linux. [Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/14876825/) is my gcc configuration if you are interested.